# Get cloned rows and columns to move inside surrounding div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've almost got a frozen header and left column working. Can anyone tell me how to get the cloned tables that contain the header row and left column to appear inside the div that encloses the main table - and how to get the cloned header and cloned column to scroll when appropriate.

Someone has posted the code below for me ... but it does not display or run properly on here when you click 'Run Code Snippet'. This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wgbgq9p2/6/) shows the display issues I am having.

```js
var $target = $("#targetT");

$("#sourceT tr").each(function() {
  var $clone = $(this).clone();
  $clone.children(':gt(0)').remove();
  $clone.height($(this).height());
  $target.append($clone);
});

var $targethead = $("#targetThead");
$("#sourceT tr:first").clone().appendTo($targethead);
$("#sourceT").find('tr').first().children().each(function(i, e) {
  $($("#targetThead").find('tr').children()[i]).width($(e).width());
});
```

```css
.gv {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: White;
}
.gv td {
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  padding: 0.2em;
}
.gvOver {
  background-color: White;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  z-index: 150;
  position: fixed;
  top: 21px;
}
.gvOver td {
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  padding: 0.2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="overflow:auto; position:absolute; top:20px; left:20px; right:500px; bottom:540px; border:1px solid red; z-index:200;">
  <table id="sourceT" class="gv">
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Heading</td>
      <td>Heading</td>
      <td>Heading</td>
      <td>Heading</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Fred</td>
      <td style="font-weight:bold; font-size:120%;">Some random text</td>
      <td style="font-weight:bold; font-size:120%;">Some random text</td>
      <td style="font-weight:bold; font-size:120%;">Some random text</td>
      <td style="font-weight:bold; font-size:120%;">Some random text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="background-color:Yellow;">Martha</td>
      <td>Some random text</td>
      <td>Some random text
        <br>Bigger row</td>
      <td>Some random text</td>
      <td>Some random text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="background-color:Lime;">William</td>
      <td>Some random text</td>
      <td>Some random text</td>
      <td>Some random text</td>
      <td>Some random text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Samantha</td>
      <td>Some random text</td>
      <td>Some random text</td>
      <td>Some random text</td>
      <td>Some random text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brian</td>
      <td>Some random text</td>
      <td>Some random text</td>
      <td>Some random text</td>
      <td>Some random text</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table id="targetT" class="gvOver"></table>
  <table id="targetThead" class="gvOver"></table>
</div>
```

Comment: nb `Please see the fiddle for the code.` by placing the relevant code in the question itself you will likely elicit more (better quality) answers. The question in addition is likely to hold more worth for future visitors. I've added the code as necessary.

Comment: As a matter of interest, how did you get the code in there? I find copying and pasting code very hard on here. Why did you remove the link to the fiddle? The code above does not run correctly on here. http://jsfiddle.net/wgbgq9p2/6/  Now I can't seem to edit my own question?

Comment: Curious to know if this question is badly phrased or not clear ... have had no comments but a lot of people have looked.